# Hackerrank New Year Chaos Swift

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I am trying to solve Hackerrank's New Year Chaos problem in Swift. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem

It is about finding the number of bribes people made on a line waiting for a roller coaster ride. For example, there is a total of 3 bribes in this list [2, 1, 5, 3, 4].

Person 2 bribed person 1.
Person 5 bribed person 3 and 4.

If there are more than 2 bribes by a person, the line becomes "Too chaotic".

I was able to get an exponential solution. However, I want to make it linear.

```
func minimumBribes(q: [Int]) -> Void {
  var bribeCount = 0
  var chaotic = false

//  for i in 0..<q.count {
//    if q[i] - (i + 1) > 2 {
//      chaotic = true
//      break
//    }
//
//    for j in i + 1..<q.count {
//      if q[i] > q[j] {
//        bribeCount += 1
//      }
//    }
//  }

    var i = 0

    while i < q.count - 1 {

    if q[i] - (i + 1) > 2 {
      chaotic = true
      break
    } else if q[i] > i + 1 {
      bribeCount += (q[i] - (i + 1))
      i += 1
    } else if q[i] <= i + 1 && q[i] > q[i + 1] && q.indices.contains(i + 1) {
      bribeCount += 1
      i += 1
    } else { // q[i] < q[i + 1]
      i += 1
    }
  }

  if chaotic {
    print("Too chaotic")
  } else {
    print(bribeCount)
  }
}
```

I commented out the exponential solution, which works. But the linear solution does not work and I cannot find out why. It works with the following arrays, [3,2,1,6,5,4], [2,5,1,3,4], [1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4], [1,3,4,2,7,6,5,9,8,11,10,14,13,12].

But there is a really long array in one of the test cases of the problem, which I do not get the correct answer with my linear solution.

For this long array, I get 966 with my exponential solution but the linear solution prints 905.

```
[2,1,5,6,3,4,9,8,11,7,10,14,13,12,17,16,15,19,18,22,20,24,23,21,27,28,25,26,30,29,33,32,31,35,36,34,39,38,37,42,40,44,41,43,47,46,48,45,50,52,49,51,54,56,55,53,59,58,57,61,63,60,65,64,67,68,62,69,66,72,70,74,73,71,77,75,79,78,81,82,80,76,85,84,83,86,89,90,88,87,92,91,95,94,93,98,97,100,96,102,99,104,101,105,103,108,106,109,107,112,111,110,113,116,114,118,119,117,115,122,121,120,124,123,127,125,126,130,129,128,131,133,135,136,132,134,139,140,138,137,143,141,144,146,145,142,148,150,147,149,153,152,155,151,157,154,158,159,156,161,160,164,165,163,167,166,162,170,171,172,168,169,175,173,174,177,176,180,181,178,179,183,182,184,187,188,185,190,189,186,191,194,192,196,197,195,199,193,198,202,200,204,205,203,207,206,201,210,209,211,208,214,215,216,212,218,217,220,213,222,219,224,221,223,227,226,225,230,231,229,228,234,235,233,237,232,239,236,241,238,240,243,242,246,245,248,249,250,247,244,253,252,251,256,255,258,254,257,259,261,262,263,265,264,260,268,266,267,271,270,273,269,274,272,275,278,276,279,277,282,283,280,281,286,284,288,287,290,289,285,293,291,292,296,294,298,297,299,295,302,301,304,303,306,300,305,309,308,307,312,311,314,315,313,310,316,319,318,321,320,317,324,325,322,323,328,327,330,326,332,331,329,335,334,333,336,338,337,341,340,339,344,343,342,347,345,349,346,351,350,348,353,355,352,357,358,354,356,359,361,360,364,362,366,365,363,368,370,367,371,372,369,374,373,376,375,378,379,377,382,381,383,380,386,387,384,385,390,388,392,391,389,393,396,397,394,398,395,401,400,403,402,399,405,407,406,409,408,411,410,404,413,412,415,417,416,414,420,419,422,421,418,424,426,423,425,428,427,431,430,429,434,435,436,437,432,433,440,438,439,443,441,445,442,447,444,448,446,449,452,451,450,455,453,454,457,456,460,459,458,463,462,464,461,467,465,466,470,469,472,468,474,471,475,473,477,476,480,479,478,483,482,485,481,487,484,489,490,491,488,492,486,494,495,496,498,493,500,499,497,502,504,501,503,507,506,505,509,511,508,513,510,512,514,516,518,519,515,521,522,520,524,517,523,525,526,529,527,531,528,533,532,534,530,537,536,539,535,541,538,540,543,544,542,547,548,545,549,546,552,550,551,554,553,557,555,556,560,559,558,563,562,564,561,567,568,566,565,569,572,571,570,575,574,577,576,579,573,580,578,583,581,584,582,587,586,585,590,589,588,593,594,592,595,591,598,599,596,597,602,603,604,605,600,601,608,609,607,611,612,606,610,615,616,614,613,619,618,617,622,620,624,621,626,625,623,628,627,631,630,633,629,635,632,637,636,634,638,640,642,639,641,645,644,647,643,646,650,648,652,653,654,649,651,656,658,657,655,661,659,660,663,664,666,662,668,667,670,665,671,673,669,672,676,677,674,679,675,680,678,681,684,682,686,685,683,689,690,688,687,693,692,691,696,695,698,694,700,701,702,697,704,699,706,703,705,709,707,711,712,710,708,713,716,715,714,718,720,721,719,723,717,722,726,725,724,729,728,727,730,733,732,735,734,736,731,738,737,741,739,740,744,743,742,747,746,745,750,748,752,749,753,751,756,754,758,755,757,761,760,759,764,763,762,767,765,768,766,771,770,769,774,773,776,772,778,777,779,775,781,780,783,784,782,786,788,789,787,790,785,793,791,792,796,795,794,798,797,801,799,803,800,805,802,804,808,806,807,811,809,810,814,812,813,817,816,819,818,815,820,821,823,822,824,826,827,825,828,831,829,830,834,833,836,832,837,839,838,841,835,840,844,842,846,845,843,849,847,851,850,852,848,855,854,853,857,856,858,861,862,860,859,863,866,865,864,867,870,869,868,872,874,875,871,873,877,878,876,880,881,879,884,883,885,882,888,886,890,891,889,893,887,895,892,896,898,894,899,897,902,901,903,905,900,904,908,907,910,909,906,912,911,915,913,916,918,914,919,921,917,923,920,924,922,927,925,929,928,926,932,931,934,930,933,935,937,939,940,938,936,943,944,942,941,947,946,948,945,951,950,949,953,952,956,954,958,957,955,961,962,963,959,964,966,960,965,969,968,971,967,970,974,972,976,973,975,979,977,981,982,978,980,983,986,984,985,989,988,987,990,993,991,995,994,997,992,999,1000,996,998]
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong with my solution. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically need to do is to first check if the element in each loop is on it's correct position. And if not you find out how much further is it from the right position if its greater than 2 you print "Too chaotic". Your solution is correct uptil this point. But if the difference is less than or equal to 2 then you need to increment the bribes and swap the indices to represent updated array. Furthermore if there are two swaps then you need to represent how the array would be effected by these 2 swaps and hence swap these values before the next iteration to ensure the array is in the condition it would be after these swaps.

Please refer to my solution below. It passes for all test cases:

```
func swapValues(  arr:inout [Int],index:Int, times: Int,  bribes:inout Int) -> Bool {

    if times == 0 {
     return false
    }

    if arr[index] > arr[index+1]  {
        let temp = arr[index+1]
        arr[index+1] = arr[index]
        arr[index] = temp
        bribes = bribes + 1
        return swapValues(arr: &arr, index: index+1, times: times-1,bribes: &bribes)

    }else{

        var diff = abs(arr[index+1] - (index+2))
        if diff > 2 {
        print("Too chaotic")
        return true
        }

       var tooChaotic = swapValues(arr: &arr, index: index+1, times: diff,bribes:&bribes)
        if tooChaotic {
            return true
        }

        return swapValues(arr: &arr, index: index, times: times, bribes: &bribes)
    }


}


func minimumBribes(q: [Int]) -> Void {

    var qC = q
    var bribes = 0


    var i = 0
    while  i <= qC.count-1{

    if i+1 == qC[i]  {
        i = i + 1
        continue
    }

    let diff = abs(qC[i] - (i+1))
    if diff > 2 {
        print("Too chaotic")
        return
    }
   var tooChaotic = swapValues(arr: &qC, index: i, times: diff, bribes: &bribes)
    if tooChaotic {
        return
    }
}
 print(bribes)
}
```

Comment: Have you Submitted the code? Running code only runs a couple of test cases. Submitting the code runs all test cases, which is more than a dozen. That long array is from test case 16 or something. I am saying this because your code does not get the correct answer for that array. But thanks for letting me know about the idea of swapping elements. I guess you could either use "qC.swapAt(i + 1, i)" or "(qC[i + 1], qC[i]) = (qC[i], qC[i + 1])" to simplify the swap process.

Comment: Please run the above code now. I have added recursion. It is important to update the values towards right first. For e.g if you hav the array 2,3,5,4. You would want to swap 5 and 4 before 3 and 5 since 5 would move further away. if you swap it with 3. So you need to check if the value at next index is greater or smaller. If its smaller simply swap. Else let the next index be swaped first and then move back.
Hope it works for you :).

Comment: Please check this code yourself as well and let me know

Comment: Thanks! That works! I am having trouble understanding the recursion part though. Is there another way to achieve it? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, you can also use a nested for loop for that.

Comment: Could you please explain the use of var "tooChaotic" in both functions?

Comment: Yes it’s a Boolean that tells us if the “Too Chaotic” condition has been met. If it is true at any point we simply print too chaotic and return the function. Else we continue till we reach the end of array. You can see that when diff is greater than 2 I return true in swap function.

Comment: Since the swap function is called from minimumbribes func hence I need to return control to this function once too chaotic condition is met. So it can end execution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution which passes all the test cases :)

```
func minimumBribes(q: [Int]) -> Void {
    var bCount = 0
    var isChaotic = false
    for (key,value) in q.enumerated() {
        if (value - 1) - key > 2 {
            isChaotic = true
            break
        }
        for index in stride(from: max(0, value - 2), to: key, by: 1){
            if q[index] > value {
                bCount += 1
            }
        }
    }
     isChaotic ? print("Too chaotic") : print("\(bCount)")  
}
```

Comment: I believe this will generate the proper output, but it exceeds the time limit given. tbh i prefer this solution since its more compact. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found this short and easy solution.

```
func minimumBribes(q: [Int]) -> Void {
    
    var ans = 0
    var shouldShow = true
    for i in stride(from: (q.count - 1), through: 0, by: -1) {
        
        if (q[i] - (i+1) > 2) {
           shouldShow = false
            break;
        }
        
        for j in  stride(from: max(0, q[i] - 2), to: i, by: 1){
            if q[j] > q[i] {
                ans += 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    if shouldShow {
        print(ans)
    } else {
        print("Too chaotic")
    }  }
```

https://github.com/AnanthaKrish/example-ios-apps

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33679527)